# Postgresql jsonb operators not working with spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, postgresql-json

I am trying to use postgresql jsonb operators with spring data jpa query as:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * from Employee e WHERE e.details @> '{\"province\":{\"city\":{\"town\": \":town\"}}, \"hobbies\": [\":hobby\"]}'",nativeQuery = true)
```

town and hobby are inputs.

There is no error but no result is returned, though records are there which meets the criteria

It seems parameter binding is not working.

What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here, `:town` and `:hobby` is inside `''`(single quote) means string literal, so parameter can't be replaced. You can use `||` to concat as string so that parameters are not inside in `''` and can be replaced.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * from Employee e WHERE e.details @> ''||'{\"province\":{\"city\":{\"town\": \"' || :town  || '\"}}, \"hobbies\": [\"' || :hobby || '\"]}'||'' ", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Did you check the solution? Feel free to ask if you faced any problem.